# Easy to develop on a URL that is changed for production?

Tags: theme-development

I have an existing website that is in production and I'd like to modify the theme.

I'd like to allow several developers to work on the new theme which would be hosted on an unrelated domain.

The question is - when it comes to moving the theme (and WordPress database with all the posts and pages) do I just need to switch out the template Uri?

Is there anything else to be mindful about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress doesn't work that way. If your developers are experienced enough to write the code dynamically, you won't need to change the template Uri.

Let's say you want to get a URL for a stylesheet, you can use:

```
echo get_template_directory_uri(). '/style.css';
```

This will automatically fetch the domain and the template's Uri. This piece of code is dynamic, it means that it will produce the correct result under any domain.

After relocating a WordPress installation to another domain, you have to do two steps.

1. Change the `siturl` and `homeurl` entries in the database. These are located under `wp_options` table, and must match your domain and WordPress installation directory.
2. Do a search replace inside your posts, to replace the old harcoded permalinks ( for example, the images in your posts ) with the new URL. All you have to is to install a plugin such as [better search replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) and replace every `old-domain.com` with `new-domain.com`.

That's all it usually takes to transfer an installation.